# Query a table to retrieve image info based on album id passed via url in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, image

Please for the life of me i can't get to solve a problem i know is a simple one. I have a table storing album names and details and another table storing image details but with a field containing the album id. I can retrieve the album data. And also pass the album id via url to another page. What i need help on is to be able to query the image table to retrieve data based on the album id passed to the image page. Lets assume in my image table i have some entries which have 8 as the album id. I want to query the image table to retrieve all image data that have the album id field as 8. I will greatly appreciate any help and direction to solving this problem.

Below are my codes.

**Album table**

```
CREATE TABLE `pgalbum` (
  `pgaID` int(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `alname` varchar(250) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,
  `aldescription` varchar(512) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,
  `alphoto` varchar(64) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,
  `aldate` varchar(10) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`pgaID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

**Image table**

```
CREATE TABLE `photogallery` (
  `pgID` int(12) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `pgaID` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(512) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,
  `photo` varchar(128) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,
  `date` varchar(20) collate latin1_general_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`pgID`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_general_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=12 ;
```

**Function to get images**

```
function get_images($start=0,$limit=0)
{
   if($start!=0 || $limit!=0)
    { $sql .= " LIMIT ". $start .", ". $limit; }

   $sql .= ";";

   $data = mysql_query($sql);
   mysql_close();
   return $data;
}
```

**Image page code**

```
$colname_rspgimage = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['pgaid'])) {
  $colname_rspgimage = $_GET['pgaid'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_connTest, $connTest);
$query_rspgimage = sprintf("SELECT pgID, pgaID, `description`, photo, `date` FROM photogallery WHERE pgaID = %s ORDER BY pgID ASC", GetSQLValueString($colname_rspgimage, "int"));
$rspgimage = mysql_query($query_rspgimage, $connTest) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rspgimage = mysql_fetch_assoc($rspgimage);
$totalRows_rspgimage = mysql_num_rows($rspgimage);


$getImages = $rspgimage;

$getImages = get_images($start,$limit);
if ($getImages && mysql_num_rows($getImages) > 0)
    {
        /* Pagination section2 */
        $getAllImages = get_images();
        $total_items = mysql_num_rows($getAllImages);
        $paginate = paginate($targetpage,$total_items,$limit,$pagenum);
        $paginate = trim($paginate);
        /* Pagination section2 End */
        if ($totalRows_rspgimage > 0) {
            echo '<table border="0" cellpadding="15" cellspacing="4">';
            $countRows = mysql_num_rows($getImages);
            $i = 0;
            if ($countRows > 0)
                {
                    while ($row_rspgimage = mysql_fetch_assoc($getImages))
                        {
                            if ($i % 4 == 0) echo '<tr>';
                            echo '<td valign="top">
                                    <a class="thumb2" href="admin/photogallery/'.$row_rspgimage['photo'].' " rel="lightbox"><img src="admin/photogallery/'.$row_rspgimage['photo'].'" border="0" width="190"/></a>
                                    <div class="clear_4"></div>
                                  </td>';
                            if ($i == $countRows - 1)
                                echo '</tr>';
                            $i++;
                        }
                }
            echo '</table>'; } // Show if recordset empty

        $output .= $paginate;
    }
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Am I missing something? It's just:

```
SELECT *
FROM photogallery
WHERE album_id = 8
```

If the album ID is a parameter, replace `8` with the appropriate parameter variable.

I don't see any reason why you need a `JOIN`, since you're not using anything from the `pgalbum` table. The album ID is available in the `photogallery` table as a foreign key.

```
SELECT photogallery.pgID, photogallery.pgaID, photogallery.description, photogallery.photo, photogallery.date 
FROM photogallery
WHERE pgaID = 8
ORDER BY pgID
```

Comment: @ Barmar: I dont want to manually put the id in the code. The album is generated dynamically. And the album id passed to the image page is based on the album that is clicked.

Comment: Say the id passed in the url is: ~/photogallery.php?pgaid=8~ But the 8 in the id is the album id. It could be 1 or 3 etc

Comment: I think the problem is in the sql statement. I tried this but it did not work.

Comment: "SELECT photogallery.pgID, photogallery.pgaID, photogallery.description, photogallery.photo, photogallery.date FROM photogallery LEFT JOIN pgalbum ON photogallery.pgID = (SELECT pgaID FROM pgalbum WHERE pgaID = pgID ORDER BY pgID ASC)";

Comment: Could you upate your question with a more detailed description of your schema, and how the two tables relate? I can't tell which of those columns are the album ID. And your ON clause makes no sense -- why do you have another `SELECT` there, instead of just the related column in the other `JOIN` table?

Comment: I have included the sql to creata the tables so you can see the fields.

Comment: I asked for explanations of what the fields are, and how they related between the tables. Which field in photogallery is the foreign key to pgalbum?

Comment: pgaID in the photogallery is the foreign key.

Comment: I figured that out. It was confusing because the query you posted has `pgaID = pgID`

Comment: Thanks for your input. Now i have modified the codes a little. But when i click an album link, what i get on the image page is a Blank page. I have 2 images in the image table. Each image has a different album id. In the album table, i have 8 albums but only two have their ids in the image table.

Comment: The issue is, when i click an album link which does not have an image associated with it, i get a no image in this album which is what i want. But when i click a link which has image in the image table, what i get is a blank page.

Comment: I don't understand your code. You perform the query I gave you, but you never do anything with the results. You just call `get_images($start, $limit)` and display those results.